# Applescript: How to select menu items in background application?

Tags: macos, applescript

My end goal is to launch system preferences in the background, go to dictation & speech, change the dictation language, and then quit system preferences. All in the background, all without people seeing.

currently my code is:

```
tell application "System Preferences" to launch
delay 1
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    click menu item "Dictation & Speech" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
    tell pop up button 1 of tab group 1 of window 1
        click
        if value is "English (United States)" then
            click menu item "Chinese (China)" of menu 1
        else
            click menu item "English (United States)" of menu 1
        end if
    end tell
end tell
quit application "System Preferences"
```

I've noticed that this works if at some point I had my System Preferences in focus/as the selected top process. After that, any application can be selected, and this code will work. Or if i change "launch" to "activate", it will work (but this defeats my purpose, since it brings System Preferences to the top)

However my code will ***not*** work if this is run when System Preferences isn't launched already. It's like the system doesn't know anything about the application and its menus until it is selected/activated.

What do I need to change?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off all, GUI scripting requires always that the affected application is in the foreground.

This is a solution which changes the respective keys in the preference files and restarts the dictation process if necessary. Opening `System Preferences` is not needed.

```
property localeIdentifiers : {"en_US", "zh_Hans_CN"}
property defaultsIdentifier : "com.apple.speech.recognition.AppleSpeechRecognition.prefs DictationIMLocaleIdentifier"

set currentLanguage to (do shell script "defaults read " & defaultsIdentifier)
if currentLanguage is item 1 of localeIdentifiers then
    set currentLanguage to item 2 of localeIdentifiers
else
    set currentLanguage to item 1 of localeIdentifiers
end if
do shell script "defaults write " & defaultsIdentifier & space & currentLanguage
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.assistant 'Session Language' " & currentLanguage
try
    do shell script "killall -HUP DictationIM"
end try
```

Comment: this does work, thank you. the identifier for chinese is: zh_Hans_CN.

however you say the scripting requires the application to be in the foreground, but I can use my code successfully without bringing it to the foreground. it just requires having been brought to the foreground previously at some point.

Comment: you definitely solved my problem more efficiently than the way I was going about it. But say i open up System Preferences, then open up Chrome and then open up my original script and run it, it will still successfully change languages. There's this weird quirk/glitches where you can see the menu item changing through the top app too.

Comment: might be in a few cases, but GUI scripting works reliably only having the affected application in the foreground without losing focus